# CSS Help: Make a text label/image not Block Button

Tags: css

I have a button on my form, and the button has an onclick event. I want to put a nice label and image on the button but notice that when hovering over these areas, the button onlick gets blocked by the other controls.

Is there any CSS I can apply to these "label" items so that the cursor doesn't think they are there but without hiding them from the user?

thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can provide the best solution?

Comment: You can add `pointer-events: none`; and it should ignore the events.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/54emL2xg/

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I figured it had been asked but had no idea what keywords to search for.